# Using SUM With Dynamic Row Numbers

Tags: excel

I am a relative beginner at excel, but my code requires some excel formulas.

We have a grid that has a total column, which sums the values of all the columns to its right. I need to use a SUM function with row indexes that are determined at runtime. The columns are always the same, let's say 'D' through 'M', but the rows could change depending on the number of entries. So it could be SUM(D2:M2), or SUM(D3:M3), and so on.

How can I write a SUM formula to access the row that the cell is in? For example, =SUM(D&ROW():M&ROW()).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use R1C1 references: `"=SUM(RC4:RC13)"`

Comment: Use `=INDIRECT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to dynamically calculate a range, use `INDIRECT`.

For example, in order to calculate the sums of columns `D:M`, use the following formula:

```
=SUM( INDIRECT("D" & ROW() & ":M" & ROW()) )
```

Which converts (If the line is `1`, of course) into

```
=SUM(D1:M1)
```

Comment: I ended up using INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(), and that worked nicely.